What do the literal meanings of "Af al pi" and "Af al gav" have to do with the actual meanings?
As far as I can tell, אף על פי/ Af Al Pi would literally translate to "nose on (my) mouth". Similarly, אף על גב/ Af Al Gav would literally translate to "nose on back". In actuality, they both mean "even though". Do mefarshim note this, and explain why this expression is worded the way it is?

From a quick sefaria search, it seems like the earliest source we have for either version is Tannaic - Mishna for Af Al Pi, Sifra for Af Al Gav.

Is 'nose' the only literal translation of 'אף'? What about 'also'?

A would-be link-only answer: קהלת יעקב מענה לשון חלק ב p. יא (23 in the full PDF), s.v. "אף על פי ואף על גב". (I'm too lazy to develop this into a proper answer. If somebody else wants to, they're welcome to it. No credit required, or wanted. Hat tip to the Otzar HaHochma forum, and user מענה איש there.)

@TamirEvan yeah. It could be also, or anger. Even "also" doesn't fully make sense, but the question is easiest to understand when I say nose. But In Hachi Nami, the main question is in regards to mouth/ back. To which your next comment is very helpful
